# Issue With adding resources in XCode 4.3.2

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4, xcode4.3

In my iPhone project I want to add a new resource folder. Lets say root folder name is "Themes" and inside that I have two folders like "Black" and "Blue".

I'm adding this "Themes" folder with both "Copy items in to destinations group folder" and "Create Folder References for any added Folders" options since I want to maintain the above folder structure inside the application (final .app folder). So in XCode this indicates as a folder in 'blue' color.

But after I do this XCode build is hang with "Attaching to ProjectName". After I remove the "Themes" folder again it works fine.

I tried clean build, reset simulator and start again options. But still the same issue.

Appreciate you help. This is killing my time for two days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually by chance I found the solution. I was trying to add the folder named "Resources". For some reason when the name is "Resources" this strange bug happens. When I renamed the folder it worked fine. This might be a bug in XCode 4.3.2.

Note: In earlier XCode versions when we create a new project there was a folder named "Resources" by default. But not in new XCode versions. May be this is a reserved name from Apple for some purposes, although there's no visible folder like that in Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange one! When I usually get this error I close/quite the simulator and xCode and then restart xCode again. Try it and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Yes. I was facing this issue with my earlier project also in my mac mini and this time I want to find a solution for this. I searched in internet and none of the solutions worked for me. I suspect this might be a apple bug related to mac mini. And im running on Lion. Who knows.

Comment: Truly you never know what you get with Xcode. After many hours of frustration, i decided to keep it simple for the poor bugger. I keep my resources folder FLAT. I encode some sense and logic in the file names so that the directory is still 'browsable' in finder. Until now, the Xcode crowd has not yet successfully mangled file names (if you except the case of files)